# XAMPP Virtual Host Document Root not working

Tags: apache, xampp, localhost, virtualhost, hosts

So I set a virtual host in my XAMPP 5.6.3. It should point to the document root I set there, but instead it points to htdocs. Why is that? Here is the virtual host setting:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@myprojectlocaldev.com
    DocumentRoot "D:/htdocs/PHP projects/myproject/myproject"
    ServerName myprojectlocaldev.com
    ErrorLog "logs/myprojectlocaldev.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/myprojectlocaldev.com-access.log" common
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
    <Directory "D:/htdocs/PHP projects/myproject/myproject">
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**UPDATE**

It turns out, the whole Virtual Host didn't work, not just the DocumentRoot.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 have used port 80 somewhere, so XAMPP should change Apache's port first before it can apply a virtual host.

Answer (score 0):

There is also another solution. Changing the default 80 port raises a lot of issues. The problem seems to be gone when we create a local SSL certificate.